# Service-Worker addEventListener, how to use the event parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, addeventlistener

I am now trying to make Push Notifications work with Node.js.

For that, I have followed some tutorial and documents that I could find on the net and I finally have something working using what is called Service Workers.

At this point both Push Notifications on Node.js and Service Workers are not something I am familiar with at all.

Here is my relevant code:

```
.....
console.log("Registering ServiceWorker.");
const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js', {
    scope: "/"
});
console.log('ServiceWorker registered.');

console.log("Registering Push.");
const subscription = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapIdKey)
});
console.log('Push registered.');

console.log("Sending Push.");
await fetch('/subscribe', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

});
console.log('Push sent.');
.....
```

and the service worker:

```
console.log('Service Worker Loaded.');

self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    const data = e.data.json;
    console.log('Push Received');
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
        body: 'It is time to go for lunch.',
        icon: 'MyLogo.png'
    })
});
```

And also this, inside my index.js file:

```
// Subscribe Route.
app.post('/subscribe',(req,res) => {
    const subscription = req.body; // Get Push Subscription Object.
    res.status(201).json({}); // Sen 201. Resource created.
    // Create PayLoad.
    const payload = JSON.stringify({title:'This is a payload-title'});
    // Pass Object to sendNotification.
    webPush.sendNotification(subscription,payload).catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

The question I want to ask is about using the second parameter of `addEventListener`.
That is the event parameter. It seems to me that this parameter must be very important to transfer information to the Service Worker, but in my example it is totally useless and I don't know how to use it.

When I run this example in FireFox or Chrome I can see this kind of notification:

[image]

One can see "undefined" displayed on the screenshot. That is what comes from data.title (coming from the e parameter).
How should I change the code to see something else than "undefined" displayed? I want to be able to make the change ouside of this block of course:

```
self.addEventListener('push', e => {...})
```

I have already tried to set some "title" field, where I thought could be a solution, but nothing worked. I am obviously not doing the right thing.

In other words, more generally speaking; what I want to know is "How to use the event parameter of addEventListener". Even a very basic example(of how to change my code for that) would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Push API specs `e.data` is an instance of `PushMessageData`. You see read more [here](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#dom-pushmessagedata) for its interface. You code should be:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {
    let data = {};

    if (e.data) {
        // IMPORTANT:
        // The following line does not use "e.data.json",
        // but "e.data.json()" !!!!!
        data = e.data.json();
    }

    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
        body: 'It is time to go for lunch.',
        icon: 'MyLogo.png'
    })
});
```

Comment: So if (for example) I wanted "My Title" to appear instead of "undefined". How should I change the code? Modify the field called any I suppose?

Comment: The code above will work, as long as the push message from server containing `title` property

Comment: Now it does not work, it only displays "undefined". And all I have tried can only display "undefined". So this is not really working. My problem (I presume) is that I don't know how to set correctly the title property.

Comment: Then it's your Push api service, you need to include the `title` in the push message

Comment: The question is exactly what you describe: "How do you do that?"

Comment: Post your Push API server code, without it I don't know what you are missing

Comment: Isn't it already in my post, in the first block of code (console.log("Sending Push.");....) ? If I need to send more code please let me know what.

Comment: That is your service worker code, not the server code which pushing the notification to client (service worker). Or are you using a Push API service?

Comment: I mainly followed a tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlYFW2zaYQM. I am not sure what you mean concerning the missing code. I also have an index.js and a package.json file that I have not posted. But I suppose it would not be very useful.

Comment: I just added a chunk of code to the post, coming from my index.js file. Hoping this will be useful.

Comment: The server code looks fine. Are you sure you are using `e.data.json()` to obtain data?

Comment: Alright! You found the issue. Indeed (as you can see in the code I posted) I was using "e.data.json" instead of "e.data.json()". And when I change it, that works and I can see the title I set. Thanks a lot. If that was an answer instead of a comment I would accept it!

Comment: Since this detail was already contained in the answer you had given above (I just hadn't noticed it). I went to edit your answer with a comment so people would not miss it, and I accepted the answer.